# can't run mirror command in bash script

Tags: bash, ftp

For some reasom I can't get the last line to work. It leaves me at the lftp user@server.org:~> prompt. Any advice?

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "This will sync the background_docs folder"
lftp ftp://user:pass@server  
mirror -r background_docs --only-missing -e
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am guessing you want lftp to run that last line,

```
mirror -r background_docs --only-missing -e
```

right?

If so, you must tell it to do so. As it is written, your script simply launches lftp, waits for it to finish, and only then it would attempt to execute the last line.

What you probably want instead is to use `lftp`'s `-e cmd` option, as such:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "This will sync the background_docs folder"
lftp -e "mirror -r background_docs --only-missing -e" ftp://user:pass@server
```

Comment: This worked, now I just have to wait a couple of minutes to accept.

Answer (score 0):

You've written a shell script. Every line gets executed as a new command at the shell. When you hit <kbd>^D</kbd> to close `lftp`, it will then try to run the `mirror` command. (Which might even exist on your system.)

If you want to send commands to a program this way, take a look at the [`expect(1)`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect) tool. There's even a learning mode available (which has given me better success than hand-written `expect` scripts).

But perhaps your `lftp(1)` command can be handled with command line parameters instead? That would be more reliable.

Comment: Expect tool would have worked as well. as iturns out this system is windows using cygwin.